# Parity transformation of the hermitian Klein-Gordon field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

I am revising some concepts of Quantum Field Theory in the book of Mandl and Shaw. In problem 3.6, among other things, we work with the real Klein-Gordon field and we want to prove the relation for the destruction operator,

$P_2 a(k) P_2^{-1} = -i\eta_p a(-k)$

where $\eta_p$ is $\pm 1$,

$P_2 = exp(i \eta_p \pi/2  \sum_k a^\dagger (k) a(-k))$,

$[a (k), a^\dagger (k')] = \delta_{kk'}$ and other commutators equal zero.

The relation is to be proven employing the fact that

$e^{i\alpha A} B e^{-i\alpha A} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (i\alpha)^n / n! B_n$,

$B_0 = B, B_n = [A,B_{n-1}], n=1,2,3,...$

What I tried so far is the following. In our case, $B = a(k)$, $A = \sum_k a^\dagger(k) a(-k)$ and $\alpha=\eta_p \pi / 2$. Then, I only need to compute the B_n,

$B_1 = [\sum_k a^\dagger(k) a(-k), a(p)] = -\sum_k [a(p), a^\dagger(k)] a(-k) = -a(-p)$,

$B_2 = -[\sum_k a^\dagger(k) a(-k), a(-p)] = \sum_k [a(-p), a^\dagger(k)] a(-k) = a(p)$

$B_3 = B_1$ and so on. Here I also used that for arbitrary operators, A, B, C,

$[A, B] = -[B, A]$ and $[A, BC] = [A, B]C + B[A, C]$

However, these results would tell me (in particular the alternating sign of p in the operator), that

$P_2 a(k) P_2^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-i\eta_p \pi/2)^n / n! a((-1)^n p)$.

From here I can not prove the relation, I think. I would need $a(-p)$ instead of $a((-1)^n p)$ to then do

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-i\eta_p \pi/2)^n / n! = e^{-i\eta_p \pi/2} = -i\eta_p$

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split this sum in $n$ even and $n$ odd. The even part gives $\cos \pi / 2$ while the odd part will give precisely what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess I was too stubborn thinking how it should be done.